# What computer cable is used for WD16001032 not power cord and where can I get one?

Tags: cable

What computer cable cord is used for a Western Digital external hard drive model Wd16001032?  Where can I purchase one?

Comment: If you could include a picture of the data connector, it may speed identification

Answer (score 1):

This seems to be an old WD Mybook drive.  It could be using the old USB A to B connectors, that or the mini B.  You should be able to lookup pictures of USB connectors by seaching Wikipedia, search for USB and scroll down or Google image search...  The connector cables are available almost anywhere and everywhere - depends on your country, but look at any local computer store.

Answer (score 0):

Does the connector look like it would mate with one of these?
[image]